# x86 Assembly pushl/popl don't work with "Error: suffix or operands invalid"

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm a newbie to assembly programming, working through [Programming Ground Up](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/) on an Ubuntu x86_64 desktop with GNU assembler v2.20.1.

I've been able to assemble/link execute my code, up until I get to using pushl/popl instructions for manipulating the stack. The following code fails to assemble:

```
 .section .data  # empty

 .section .text
.globl _start
_start:
 pushl $1       # push the value 1 onto the stack
 popl %eax      # pop 1 off the stack and into the %eax register
 int $0x80      # exit the program with exit code '1'
```

Using "as test.s -o test.o", these errors appear on the terminal and test.o is not created:

```
test.s: Assembler messages: 
test.s:9: Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'push'
test.s:10:  Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'popl'
```

I've checked the documentation, and the operands I'm using for pushl and popl are valid. This isn't exactly a debugging question--so what's wrong with my code? Or is it my assembler?

Comment: This looks like 32 bit code but you're trying to assemble for 64 bit (default on x86_64). Pass an appropriate flag to as to build as 32 bit, e.g. `as -arch i386 ...`

Comment: I believe Paul has the right answer.  You probably need --32 to as.

Comment: I mention the textbook I'm using to learn x86 assembly (_Programming Ground Up_ seems to be a popular, free one)--is there a similarly popular textbook for x86/64bit (free's not that important) that you'd recommend for newbies?

I realize this may be much too big a question to be asking here, but what's the difference between 32bit and 64bit as a first experience with assembly programming?

Comment: `int $0x80` / `eax=1` is `sys_exit(ebx)`.  The 1 is the code for the exit system call; the return status goes in EBX in the 32-bit ABI.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6

Comment: [legal push operand sizes in 64-bit mode are word and qword, but not dword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushes-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-spec).

Comment: The differences are simple once you know one or the other and understand what's going on, but when learning, stick to the mode that your book / tutorial / guide is for.  **[Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain)**.  Don't try to port 32-bit examples to 64-bit (or vice versa) *while* you're learning them for the first time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In 64-bit mode you cannot push and pop 32-bit values; you need `pushq` and `popq`.

Also, you will not get a proper exit this way. On 32-bit x86, you would need to set `%eax` to 1 to select the `exit()` system call, *and* set `%ebx` to the exit code you actually wish. On 64-bit x86 (that's what you are using), conventions are different: the system call number for `exit()` is 60, not 1; the first system call parameter goes in `%rdi`, not `%rbx`; the system-call invocation opcode is not `int $0x80` but the special, x86-64-only opcode `syscall`.

Which leads to:

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    pushq   $60
    popq    %rax
    pushq   $1
    popq    %rdi
    syscall
```

(each `push`/`pop` sequence can be replaced with a simple `mov` (like `mov $60, %eax`) of course; I suppose that you are trying to explicitly test `push` and `pop`, optimize for code-size, or avoid `0` bytes in the machine code (for an exploit payload))

---

Related:

- [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64)
- [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)

Comment: thank you, you guys both rock :) and yes, I was just using push/pop to demonstrate the problem, not reinventing mov. Though I was ignorant of the fact that x32 vs. x64 architecture was an issue.

Comment: where would a good reference on the differences between 32/64 be found? i.e. what resource can I use in conjunction with this book to program on 64bit?

Comment: You may want to have a look at Intel's manuals: http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm (that's complete and quite readable, but huge).

Comment: thanks Thomas, there seems to be a starting article before this http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly/?wapkw=%28assembly%29

Comment: The 32-bit `int $0x80` ABI is available (but not recommended) in 64-bit mode , so the OP's program does successfully invoke `sys_exit(0)` instead of crashing.  (Linux initializes all the regs to 0 before entering user-space, so EBX will be 0 unless the binary is dynamically linked, in which case it will contain whatever ld.so left.)  See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)

Answer (score 15):

I recently started following these examples too, I found the following worked:

1. Add `.code32` to the top of your assembly code
2. Assemble with the `--32` flag
3. Link with the `-m elf_i386` flag

You can see my example [here](https://github.com/agam/LearningAssembly/blob/master/power.s)

Comment: In 32-bit instruction, link with the -m elf_i386 flag,the program can run correctly. But how to make it work in 64-bit instruction? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401047/how-to-make-it-work-in-x86-64-assembly

Comment: **You don't need `.code32`, and in fact should avoid it so you get noisy failure at build time** (from instructions like `push %eax`) **if you forget the other 2 steps and build as 64-bit**.  All `.code32` does is let you put 32-bit machine code inside a 64-bit executable, where it will decode "wrong" at run-time.  (Or to switch back to 32-bit after `.code16` or `.code32`). If that's not what you want, don't use it!  See also [building 32-bit executables with 64-bit GNU tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain)

Answer (score 7):

You need to replace the push/pop sequence with

```
pushq $1       # push the value 1 onto the stack
popq %rax      # pop 1 off the stack and into the %eax register
```

Note the error message is "**suffix** or operand invalid", you only checked the second part of the logical `OR` in the error message, maybe because you weren't exactly sure what the suffix means: it's the "l".

Edit: Please see Thomas answer for an explanation why your code won't work anyway even if it assembles.

Comment: Yeah, I think I just mentally blocked the suffix part bcs I had no idea what it meant. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error working through the same book.
I created the following shell script (att.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
as --32 $1.s -o $1
ld -melf_i386 $1.o -o $1
./$1
echo $?
```

Which I then made executable and ran (assuming an input file myfile.s):

```
chmod +x ./att.sh
./att.sh myfile
```

Answer (score -1):

You may push any value without push command like that

```
decq %rsp
movb $0, (%rsp)
```

push 1 byte on stack
and pop after

```
movb (%rsp), %al
incq %rsp
```

And any other size. As compilator don't generate any  error and all will work good! To address may use rbp register instead of rsp. Now is allowed.

Comment: You're totally missing the point.  The OP has 32-bit code, and accidentally built it as 64-bit.  They *want* to do a 32-bit push to match the `pop %eax` as a 3-byte way to set `eax=1`  Your code would need `movzbl (%rsp), %eax` to do that.  Also, you usually don't want to misalign `%rsp` like that, because a signal handler could run at any time.  And no, you can't always use `%rbp`; making a frame pointer is optional.

Comment: And anyway, the OP didn't want to avoid `push`/`pop`.  `push $1` works fine in 64-bit mode (as a 64-bit push.)