# Invalid instruction suffix for push when assembling with gas

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, assembly, gnu-assembler

When assembling a file with GNU assembler I get the following error:

> hello.s:6: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'

Here's the file that I'm trying to assemble:

```
        .text
LC0:
        .ascii "Hello, world!\12\0"
.globl _main
_main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $8, %esp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        movl    $0, %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        call    __alloca
        call    ___main
        movl    $LC0, (%esp)
        call    _printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

What is wrong here and how do I fix it?

The problem is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5485468/471164) although errors and instructions in questions are different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [x86 Assembly pushl/popl don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485468/x86-assembly-pushl-popl-dont-work)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

64bit instructions

By default most operations remain 32-bit and the 64-bit counterparts are invoked by the fourth bit in the REX prefix. This means that each 32-bit instruction has it's natural 64-bit extension and that extended registers are for free in 64-bit instructions

```
movl $1,  %eax     # 32-bit instruction
movq $1,  %rax     # 64-bit instruction

pushl %eax         # Illegal instruction
pushq %rax         # 1 byte instruction encoded as pushl %eax in 32 bits
pushq %r10         # 2 byte instruction encoded as pushl preceeded by REX
```

Answer (score 23):

Prepend `.code32` as your first line.

`--32` option will change the target to 32 bit platform.

Comment: How exactly do I use this?

Answer (score 13):

Are you assembling with a 64-bit assembler?  Your code looks like it's 32-bit.  I get this error with your code when using a 64-bit assembler:

```
example.s:6:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
```

But it works fine with a 32-bit assembler.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use a "64 bit syntax", or you can use the " --32 " option: by this way the assembler chages its target to the i386 platform.