# How to make it work in x86-64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Recently I'm learning assembly and now i have some confusion. I learned it from [Professional Assembly language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579010).

My System's arch:

```
#uname -m
x86_64
```

This is my code:

```
.section .data
output:
   .asciz "This is section %d\n"
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    pushq $1
    pushq $output
    call printf
    addq $8, %rsp
    call overhere
    pushq $3
    pushq $output
    call printf
    addq $8, %rsp
    pushq $0
    call exit
overhere:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    pushq $2
    pushq $output
    call printf
    addq $8, %rsp
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

I assemble, link and run it like this, getting the error message shown:

```
#as -o calltest.o calltest.s
#ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc -o calltest calltest.o
#./calltest 
Segmentation fault
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Avoid coding assembler code (especially in hundreds of lines): the compiler is optimizing better than you could. But read the emitted code (e.g. using `gcc -O -Wall -fverbose-asm -S`) and perhaps use `asm` instructions inside your C functions.

Comment: Is that book of yours aimed at x86-64 assembly? If not, you're probably not going to have much use for it if you want to write 64-bit programs. The calling convention is not the same in 64-bit mode as in 32-bit mode.

Comment: In 32-bit instruction, Link with the -m elf_i386 flag the program can run correctly. But how to make it work in 64-bit instruction?

Comment: I've cut down your question to just the part where you're actually asking a question. The problems you resolved previously don't add much insight to your question and only make your question look off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x86_64` has another kind of passing arguments, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI

This is how your example would work:

```
.section .data
output:
   .asciz "This is section %d\n"
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movq $output, %rdi      # 1st argument
    movq $1, %rsi           # 2nd argument
    xorl %eax, %eax         # no floating point arguments
    call printf
    call overhere
    movq $output, %rdi      # 1st argument
    movq $3, %rsi           # 2nd argument
    xorl %eax, %eax         # no floating point arguments
    call printf
    xor %edi, %edi
    call exit
overhere:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movq $output, %rdi      # 1st argument
    movq $2, %rsi           # 2nd argument
    xorl %eax, %eax         # no floating point arguments
    call printf
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: FWIW, that is the System V ABI for x86_64. In Win64, this would be entirely different again.